# What is the kbhit equivalent for Windows CE?

Tags: windows-ce

What is the kbhit equivalent for Windows CE?  In particular, I'm wondering about windows CE 6.0.  I guess more generally, is there a way to do non-blocking reads from stdin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [kbhit equivalent for Windows CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042479/kbhit-equivalent-for-windows-ce)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to process the WM_KEYDOWN messages in Windows CE. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms910665.aspx) for some details on how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that this is for a console application.

Comment: How would a user know what happens to his key input when there is nothing visible on screen?

Comment: Think of an embedded system running CE, with no display.  CE has a telnet server so that you can connect over the network and run console applications.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is looking for a key, you could poll using [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932743.aspx) or [GetAsyncKeySytate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929803.aspx).