# kbhit equivalent for Windows CE

Tags: c++, keyboard, windows-ce, keyboard-events

I know this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926844/what-is-the-kbhit-equivalent-for-windows-ce) and I have tried searching on Google but I don't seem to be able to find a decent answer to this.

I want a console application I am writing to exit when a user presses a button.  It's written in C++ and will be deployed on Windows CE6.

Currently the same code, on XP, uses this to perform actions until the keyboard is hit

```
//App entry
while (!_kbhit()) { /* Awesome code goes here */ }
//App exits here
```

Can anyone help me :)

Comment: Yes, exactly this question has been asked before and you shouldn't create a duplicate.

Comment: That's ridiculous.  What if someone knows how to solve this question but just _didn't happen_ to be on SO at precisely the same time at which that question was asked!!

Comment: Then you alter the original question so it comes back to the top - you don't duplicate the questions.  We don't want 50 of the same question, some with and some without answers, or some with answer A and some with B or some other mix of answers, comments, etc.  That's the whole purpose of "Close As Duplicate"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the kbhit equivalent for Windows CE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926844/what-is-the-kbhit-equivalent-for-windows-ce)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [getchar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859646.aspx)?

It may be necessary to direct standard input/output to the console using [SetStdioPathW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886820.aspx).

-PaulH